# PHP Auth0 JWT Token generator invalid signature

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt, auth0

I use Codeigniter and [JWT-library](https://github.com/b3457m0d3/JWT-CodeIgniter) to generate JWT token for my Auth0 API. If I check generated token on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and write my secret I decode token as well. When I try to use generated token on Auth0 API I got error:

```
{
   "statusCode": 401,
   "error": "Unauthorized",
   "message": "Invalid signature received for JSON Web Token validation",
   "attributes": {
      "error": "Invalid signature received for JSON Web Token validation"
   }
}
```

My code is next:

```
$this->load->library("JWT");
$CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$token = $this->jwt->encode(array(
    'aud'=>$CONSUMER_KEY,
    'scopes'=>array('users'=>array('actions'=>array('read'))),
    'iat'=>strtotime("now"),
    'jti'=>'RApplrxJ7rrlTDM6swoY2tV2azr5fo5b' //random string
), $CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem and verified token signature?

UPDATE: Now I noticed that if checked "secret base64 encoded" I got invalid signature, and that should have been checked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with *"my Auth0 API"*? For HMAC based algorithms, which seems to be the case the code that verifies the JWT signature must use the same secret has the code that signed it.

Comment: I found solution and I can say that neither one php library from jwt.io doesn't work. Solution it's very simple but I spent one month to found because no one mention nowhere what to do. I just decode my secret before I encode everything else with php library. Now it works.

Comment: If you've found the solution could you mark your question as self-solved :)